# GIT stops after resolving deltas on git clone

Tags: git

i try to git clone via git bash on windows 7 (64-bit) with 4GB RAM
but if i try it on machine with 8GB it is fine work.

what i type and get:

```
     git clone  user@url:/rep
     Cloning into heverest...
     remote: Counting objects: 85868, done.
     remote: Compressing objects: 100% (38411/38411), done.
     remote: Total 85868 (delta 44254), reused 82916 (delta 41990)
     Receiving objects: 100% (85868/85868), 303.58 MiB | 1.12 MiB/s, done.
     fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 521762198 bytes)
     fatal: index-pack failed
```

config:

```
    [core]
        filemode = false
        bigFileThreshold = 2048m
     [pack]
        windowMemory = 2048m
        threads = 0
        window = 0
        deltaCacheSize = 0
```

what i need to do?
what i need to change in config?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292903/git-on-windows-out-of-memory-malloc-failed

Comment: 2 answers from links not help me

Comment: Search for "index pack failed", the actual error message: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659823/heroku-git-clone-gives-fatal-index-pack-failed
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629748/index-pack-failed
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766876/how-to-solvefatal-index-pack-failed